# How can I add EFS to an Airflow deployment on Amazon-EKS?

Tags: airflow, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

Kubernetes and EKS newbie here.

I've set up an Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) cluster and added an Airflow deployment on top of it using the [official HELM chart for Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html). I configured gitsync and can successfully run my DAGS. For some of the DAGs, I need to save the data to an Amazon EFS. I installed the Amazon EFS CSI driver on eks following the instruction on the [amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html).

Now, I can create a new pod with access to the NFS but the airflow deployment broke and stay in a state of `Back-off restarting failed container`. I also got the events with `kubectl -n airflow get events --sort-by='{.lastTimestamp}` and I get the following messages:

```
TYPE      REASON               OBJECT                                            MESSAGE

Warning   BackOff              pod/airflow-scheduler-599fc856dc-c4pgz            Back-off restarting failed container

Normal    FailedBinding        persistentvolumeclaim/redis-db-airflow-redis-0    no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

Warning   ProvisioningFailed   persistentvolumeclaim/ebs-claim                   storageclass.storage.k8s.io "ebs-sc" not found

Normal    FailedBinding        persistentvolumeclaim/data-airflow-postgresql-0   no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

I have tried this on EKS version 1.22.

I understand from this that airflow is expecting to get an EBS volume for its pods but the NFS driver changed the configuration of the pvs.

The pvs before I install the driver are this:

```
NAME CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-######   100Gi      RWO            Delete           Bound    airflow/logs-airflow-worker-0       gp2                     1d

pvc-######   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    airflow/data-airflow-postgresql-0   gp2                 1d

pvc-######   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    airflow/redis-db-airflow-redis-0    gp2                     1d
```

After I install the EFS CSI driver, I see the pvs have changed.

```
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE

efs-pvc   5Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    efs-storage-claim   efs-sc                  2d
```

I have tried deploying airflow before or after installing the EFS driver and in both cases I get the same error.

How can I get access to the NFS from within Airflow without breaking the Airflow deployment on EKS. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error above `no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set` and `storageclass.storage.k8s.io "ebs-sc" not found`, you have to deploy a storage class called `efs-sc` using the EFS CSI driver as a provisioner.

Further documentation could be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/access_points/README.md#create-access-points-in-efs)

An example of creating your missing storage class and persistent volume could be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/access_points/specs/example.yaml)

These steps are also described in the AWS EKS [user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html#efs-sample-app)

Comment: What you are sharing is for the EFS which is working on my eks deployment, I am able to deploy a pod that uses efs. The problem I am having is that when I install the efs driver, the ebs stops working. As you copied in your solution, the message I am getting is `storageclass.storage.k8s.io "ebs-sc" not found`, look how it says ebs and not efs.